# Call local_auth in flutter resume state will request authentication continuously

Tags: flutter, dart, binding, bioinformatics

I'm using the local_auth package to lock app services after login if the user closes the app
what I want is to call the authentication function in the resume state of AppLifecycleState (when the user opens the app again)
but this prompt authentication infinitely

```
class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}
  @override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
switch (state) {
  case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.paused:
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
   {
      await _auth.authenticate(
      useErrorDialogs: true,
      stickyAuth: true,
    );
    }
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    break;
}
}
   @override
void dispose() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
super.dispose();
}
```

This will call authentication forever
how to solve this?

Comment: Have you got any solution to this problem ?

Comment: callback your function in AppLifecycleState.paused instead of AppLifecycleState. resumed